# Is there a way to use wildcards in '==' test in tcl?

Tags: tcl

This might not be possible but is there a way to pass a regular expression in tcl.
I have this function that i cannot change which you pass in a string if finds something and compares them to see if they are equal.

```
proc check {a } {
    // find b in the database
    if {$a == $b} {
        puts "equals"
    } {
        puts "Not equals"
    }   
 }
```

The problem is that the function uses '=='. this only matches if they are exact, but i need to have wild cards in 'a' so that 'a' and 'b' are equal if 'a' and 'b' start with the same words.

Answer (score 3):

> I have this function that i cannot change

Why? In tcl, you could easily redefine it with

```
proc check {a } {
    # find b in the database
    if {[string match -nocase $a $b]} {
        puts "equals"
    } {
        puts "Not equals"
    }   
}
```

Or you could redefine `if`, although not recommended.

You could even search and replace the `if` line at runtime with

```
proc check [info args check] [string map {
    {if {$a == $b}} {if {[string match -nocase $a $b]}}
} [info body check]]
```

So: Why can't you change the function?

Comment: it is legacy code that cannot be changed / not allowed to change

Comment: Ok, to summarize: You have the task that requires to change `check`, but you are not allowed to do that. Which means that you can not complete this task successful.

Comment: consider the hotpatches in my post, maybe one of them is allowed ;)

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of the `==` operator is fixed; it always does an equality test. Indeed it does an equality test that prefers to do numeric equality and only falls back to string equality if it has no other way.

Therefore, to change the behavior of `check` you have to get *really* tricky.

---

I'd look at using execution traces to intercept something inside of `check` so that you can then put a read trace on the local `a` variable so that when you read it you get actually whether its value matches something according to complex rules. (`b` can probably just hold a `1` for boolean truth.) The code to do this is sufficiently mind-bendingly complex that I'd *really* try to avoid doing it!

Much easier, if you can, is to redefine `proc` so that you can put a prefix on the body of `check` so you can apply the trace there. Or even massage the test itself.

```
# Rename the command to something that nothing else knows about (tricky!)
rename proc my_real_proc

my_real_proc proc {name arguments body} {
    # Replace a simple equality with a basic no-case pattern match
    if {$name eq "check"} {
        set body [string map {{$a == $b} {[string match -nocase $b $a]}} $body]
    }
    # Delegate to the original definition of [proc] for everything else
    uplevel my_real_proc $name $arguments $body
}
```

So long as you run that code before the definition of `check`, you'll change the code (without “changing the code”) and get the sort of capabilities you want.

Comment: If you replace the primitives of a language (and in Tcl, such a thing is easy), you can get every program to do that what you want without touching that code.